# How to get stack trace of an exception in Scala to print it?

Tags: java, exception, scala

In a program of mine I'd like to catch all exceptions and explicitly print them (to be able to proceed with finally while still seeing exceptions).

So I've tried this:

```
try {
  ...
}
catch {
  case ex : Exception => {
    println ("\n" + ex)
    println ("\n" + ex.getStackTrace + "\n")
  }
}
finally {
  ...
}
```

But this (using getStackTrace) itself causes "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space". What am I doing wrong? I am sure I have plenty of free JVM heap memory free before getting this (as I've tried causing an exception in the very beginning of the program).

Comment: What kind of exception was thrown in the `try` block?

Comment: @larsmans, it's an IllegalArgumentException and I throw it by my own.

Comment: Do you use Scala 2.7.x or Scala 2.8.x?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should post an exact, standalone working example of this because this works for me using 2.8.0 (i.e. exhibits no memory problems at all):

```
scala> def foo( f : () => Unit) : Unit = try {
     | f()
     | } catch { case e : Exception => println("H" + e.getStackTrace) }
foo: (f: () => Unit)Unit

scala> foo(() => throw new NullPointerException)
H[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@30a4effe
```

I wonder whether you have an exception *which is its own `cause`*? Conversely it may be the case that your program *is* running very low on memory ([32Mb is the default on a client-class machine by the way](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc5.0/ergo5.html)) and you have a very deep stack (not uncommon in scala-land!)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to allocate more permgen space. In Java you do this with a JVM argument:

```
-XX:MaxPermGen=256m
```

You can set JVM args to be used by Scala by setting an environment variable:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermGen=256m"
```

Comment: I think this is not a correct answer. Because I have this parameter unaltered (it is 256m by default, AFAIK) and use very little memory before throwing an exception. The problem only occurs if I try to access Exception.getStackTrace.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to something larger? It certainly seems fishy that getting a stack trace is exhausting your permgen space, but maybe if you can increase the memory to the point where you can actually examine the stack trace you'll be able to get some insight into what's going on.

Comment: If I don't catch exception, it (including stack trace) is printed correctly and looks sane. But this - "maybe if you can increase the memory to the point where you can actually examine the stack trace you'll be able to get some insight into what's going on" - sounds rational, thanks for the idea.